# Stable equivalence of framings - examples with large number of stabilizations needed

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology, vector-bundles

Let $\xi$ be a vector bundle over a closed manifold $X$.  A framing (or trivialization) of $\xi$ is an isomorphism of bundles $\xi \to \epsilon^n$ where $\epsilon^n$ is an $n$-dimensional trivial bundle over $X$.  A stable framing of $\xi$ is an isomorphism $\xi \oplus \epsilon^k \to \epsilon^{n+k}$.  Typically, two framings are considered equivalent if they are homotopic through bundle isomorphisms and two stable framings are considered equivalent if some stabilization of them is homotopic through bundle isomorphisms.

I would like an example of a sequence bundles $\xi_k$ (ideally, all over the same base space) and pairs of trivializations $\phi_1, \phi_2 : \xi \oplus \epsilon^m \to \epsilon^n$ with the property that $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ are stably equivalent but $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ are not equivalent when just stabilized $k$ times.

Comment: When talking about equivalence of stable frames, do you mean that there is some $l$ and a map $\xi\oplus \epsilon^k \oplus \epsilon^l \rightarrow \epsilon ^{n+k+l}$ so that restricted to $\xi\oplus \epsilon^k$ it is the original framing and restricted to $\epsilon ^l$ it is the identity? Or can the restriction to $\epsilon ^l$ be something besides the identity?

Comment: @ConnorMalin The restriction to $\epsilon^l$ should be the identity